# Pivot table : select aggregate column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle12c

i am trying to transpose rows into columns using pivot but i am not able to add aggregate column t_flg in the final output . any suggestions on this.

```
 CREATE TABLE "TEST_PI" 
   ("ID" NUMBER(20,0), 
    "T_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "T_FLG" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)
   ) 


INSERT INTO test_pi VALUES (100 ,EVENT, N);
INSERT INTO test_pi VALUES (100 ,EVENT, N);
INSERT INTO test_pi VALUES (200 ,EVENT, Y);
INSERT INTO test_pi VALUES (200 ,EVENT, Y);
INSERT INTO test_pi VALUES (300 ,EVENT, Y);
INSERT INTO test_pi VALUES (300 ,EVENT, Y);
```

i tried

```
 WITH pivot_data AS (
 select ID,T_NAME,T_FLG from TEST_PI
 )
SELECT *
FROM   pivot_data
PIVOT (
MIN(T_FLG) 
FOR T_NAME 
IN  ('EVENT'      AS EVENTS,
     'CAT'        AS CAT
    )
);
```

expected output

```
ID  T_FLG EVENTS  CAT
100  N     N      N
200  Y     Y      Y
300  Y     Y      Y
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Where do the "Y"s come from?  There are none in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation.  I think this is what you want:

```
select id, min(t_flg) as t_flg,
       min(case when t_name = 'EVENT' then t_value end) as event,
       min(case when t_name = 'CAT' then t_value end) as cat
from test_pi
group by id;
```

Comment: Sorry I have corrected the data. Is it possible to get this output using pivot?

Comment: @kashi . . . I discourage the use of `pivot`, always preferring conditional aggregation.